# 'sudo apt-get purge mysql*' returns many dependency errors

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have tried to remove mysql. 
I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 and python 3.5.1+ .
The terminal wrote me the error shown below.
What's the problem? What did I do wrong?

```
heartprogrammer@heartprogrammer-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysqltcl' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-agent' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-tools' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-utilities' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-common' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-sandbox' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-monitor' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltuner' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench-data' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-source-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Package 'mysql-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-mmm-agent' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-mmm-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-mmm-monitor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-mmm-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-sandbox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-utilities' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-workbench' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-workbench-data' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltcl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltuner' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-source-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libaio1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmysqlclient20:i386* libqt4-sql-mysql:i386* mysql-client-5.7*
  mysql-client-core-5.7* mysql-common* mysql-server* mysql-server-5.7*
  mysql-server-core-5.7*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 165 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216375 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Removing libmysqlclient20:i386 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing mysql-server (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Purging configuration files for mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing mysql-common (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-common (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing mysql-common, directory '/etc/mysql' not empty so not removed
Removing mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
 python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1); however:
  Package python-cairo is not configured yet.
 python-gtk2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); however:
  Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gimp:
 gimp depends on python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gimp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-gtk2
 gimp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu and version of python that you are using (`python --version`)

Comment: I have corrected it

Comment: @guntbert I think the length of the text to include is not a problem: It gets enclosed by a scrollbox autobatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql*`

This shall force remove mysql packages without first configuring the unconfigured python packages.

Comment: You could also try: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` first before running the `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to view list of the installed MySQL parts.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

and then try to purge them one-by-one.
Looks like you have dependency problems and apt-get can't automatically resolve them.